# Where can I buy a keyboard with an Ubuntu logo on the super key?

Tags: hardware, keyboard

Anyone knows where I can get a keyboard to buy with the Ubuntu logo on the super key?
If not where can I get some durable small plastic Ubuntu logos about 8 to 9 mm in diameter that I can use to glue on my keyboard?

Comment: For what it's worth, there are also keyboards that have an [entirely blank super key](http://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-media/permalink/moORLZ5XED7D0J/B003PHJJV6/ref=cm_ciu_images_pl_link).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You could buy one from [ZaReason.com](http://zareason.com/shop/Ubuntu-Keyboard.html), but they are out of stock right now.

[System76](http://www.system76.com/) gives away free Ubuntu stickers, including ones for the <kbd>Super</kbd> key, instructions on how to get them: 
 http://www.system76.com/community/stickers/

[image]

Comment: I requested stickers at least twice, but I never received them :/

Comment: That's awesome! Free stickers! I'll surely send my pre-addressed envelope next week; there's a supplier in Canada!

Comment: I got the free 'powered by Ubuntu' stickers (a couple months ago) but no meta key sticker. Maybe they were out at the time?

Comment: I have a System76 laptop but I just peeled the round sticker off the Super key as the edges were catching cruft and the thickness bothered me. I'm still looking for a full key black background Linux-related sticker.

Comment: The super key stickers are only for the US :(

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know of any with the Ubuntu logo, but I do know that Das Keyboards sell Linux Keycaps for their super keys (with Tux on it) on their keyboards. http://www.daskeyboard.com/products/. Canonical also sell an Ubuntu flexible keyboard in their store (with the Ubuntu logo along the side) but the super keys still contain the windows logo. http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=800.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

The Canonical store sells packs of stickers [here](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=718) that you can use to replace all the standard Windows branding on your machine, including two that you can choose from to cover the Windows logo on your super key--one orange-on-white, and one white-on-orange. Many of the other stickers come in these two variants, too.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a place you can order custom keys for mechanical keyboards:

[wasdkeyboards.com](http://www.wasdkeyboards.com/index.php/products/printed-keycap-singles/custom-art-cherry-mx-keycaps.html#ad-image-1)

[image]

Pair that with the Ubuntu logo:

[image]

and this could be very cool!

Answer (score 1):

If you are into mechanical keyboards, you can get [Ubuntu Logo keys](http://www.keyboardco.com/product/ubuntu-logo-windows-keys-2-keycaps-for-cherry-mx-switches.asp) for Cherry MX switches from KeyboardCo.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend the Turbot Water-resistant Anti-ghosting 87-Key Wired Mechanical Gaming Keyboard With Blue Switch. It's less than $40 USD (I paid $34) and it fits the keycaps from WASD Keyboards. A pair of Ubuntu OS Keycaps are only $6 on WASD Keyboards. There are other low priced mechanical keyboards as well, any of those will do so long as they are compatible with Cherry MX switches.